# Optimise complexity of combinatoric algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, combinations, mathematical-optimization

I'm struggling to optimise my code on the following problem:

> You are given N boxes indexed from 1 to N.  Each box contains either
> no coins or one coin.  The number of empty boxes and the number of
> boxes with one coin are denoted by n0 and n1, respectively.  You take
> a random subset of the boxes where each subset has the same same
> probability to be selected.  The empty set and the set itself are
> considered a subset.
>
> Given n0 and n1, what is the probability that the total number of
> coins in the random subset is even?
>
> Constraint: N = n0 + n1 < 100000
>
> #### EXAMPLES
>
> 1
>
> - Input: n0 = 1, n1 = 0
> - Output: 1.0
> - Explanation: There are two subsets: [] and [0]. Both of them have an even sum.
>
> 2
>
> - Input: n0 = 0, n1 = 2
> - Output: 0.5
> - Explanation: There are four subsets: [], [1], [1], and [1, 1]. The sum of [] and [1,1] is even.

So far I attempted an implementation in Python 3.8, but I think it works ok, but it takes very long to compute for larger numbers.

```
prob = 0

n0 = 1
n1 = 4

for j in range(0, n1+1):
        if (j % 2 == 0):
            prob += comb(n1, j)

total_prob = (2**n0 * prob) / (2 ** (n0+n1))
total_prob
```

Comment: This is an interesting task. I must say it has nothing to do with Python though. It would probably be better to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Roger--what are the approximate size of large numbers i.e. hundreds, thousands millions, etc?

Comment: `Constraint: N = n0 + n1 < 100000`
So yeah below 100k !

Comment: @Roger--with numbers that large the combinations your posted approach above becomes non-computable.  You can see this from [Strirling's Approximation for factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) which has n! ~ (n^n)*sqrt(2*pi*n).  With n~ 100K, n^n ~ (100k)^(100k) ~ (10^5)^100k ~ 10^500k which becomes non-computable (by comparison there are 10^82 atoms in the universe).

Comment: @Roger--although we can't compute the sum, it simplifies analytically to my posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your algorithm is correct, total_prob can be determined analytically as follows.

This summation:

```
prob = 0
for j in range(0, n1+1):
        if (j % 2 == 0):
            prob += comb(n1, j)
```

Is computing the even terms of binomial coefficients i.e.:

```
comb(n1, 0) + comb(n1, 2) + ... + comb(n1, J)
    where J is even and J>=n1
```

It's okay for J > n1, since comb(n1, J) = 0 for J > n1 (definition of nCr)

This sum is simply [source](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Even_Index_Binomial_Coefficients):

```
prob = 2**(n1 - 1)
```

Substituting for prob in total_prob equation:

```
total_prob = (2**n0) *(2**(n1-1)) / (2 ** (n0+n1))
total_prob = 2**(n0 + n1 - 1)/(2**(n0+n1))

total_prob = 0.5  (always)
```

Comment: I have another similar question that seems less trivial to simplify, if you'd like to have a look it's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64218390/optimise-complexity-of-combinatoric-algorithm-2
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def comb(n, k):  # Calculates the combination based on n and k values
    return math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n - k) //math.factorial(k)

def question(n0, n1):    # probability that the total number of coins in the random subset is even
    """probability of sums of even / total probability"""
    p = 0
    for i in range(0, n1+1):
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            p += comb(n1, i)

    return  p / (2 ** n1)
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does, and how it does it; never just post code on its own as an answer.

Comment: I know it is, but you have to explain how you created your solution; what you changed, what it does, and how it does it. Otherwise the person who asked the question won't learn anything.